# mysqli_query() : "mysql server has gone away" and "Error reading result set's header" on uploads >3M

Tags: php, mysql, upload

I have both error in the title when I'm trying to upload a file bigger then about 3 megabytes to my server.

Here is what I tried in `my.ini`:

```
# The MySQL server
[wampmysqld]
SET SESSION wait_timeout=28800
SET GLOBAL wait_timeout=28800
interactive_timeout=3000
wait_timeout=3000
mysql.connect_timeout = 1000
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock
key_buffer_size = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 100M
sort_buffer_size = 8K
net_buffer_length = 512K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
basedir=c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17
log-error=c:/wamp/logs/mysql.log
datadir=c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17/data

[mysqld]
SET SESSION wait_timeout=28800
SET GLOBAL wait_timeout=28800
max_allowed_packet = 100M
interactive_timeout=3000
wait_timeout=3000
port=3306
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = TRUE
```

and in `php.ini`:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 500M
```

The table containing the file has `longblob` data type for the content. I still have these errors after these changes. What should I do?